Compatibility of natural transformations in a six-functor formalism
Suppose we are given a six-functor formalism and a cartesian diagram
$$\require{AMScd} \begin{CD} X @>\tilde{g}>> Z \\ @V \tilde{f} V V @V Vf V \\ Y @>g>> W\end{CD} \,.$$
There are two ways of defining a natural transformation $\tilde{g}_* \to \tilde{g}_* \tilde{f}^! \tilde{f}_!$.  First, one can take the transformation $\operatorname{id} \to \tilde{f}^! \tilde{f}_!$ adjoint to the identity $\tilde{f}_! \to \tilde{f}_!$ and compose on the left with $\tilde{g}_*$
to get a transformation $\tilde{g}_* \to \tilde{g}_* \tilde{f}^! \tilde{f}_!$.
Second, one can compose $\operatorname{id} \to f^! f_!$ on the right with $\tilde{g}_*$
to get a morphism $\tilde{g}_* \to f^! f_! \tilde{g}_*$, and then compose with the morphisms $f^! f_! \tilde{g}_*\to f^! g_* \tilde{f}_! \xrightarrow{\sim} \tilde{g}_* \tilde{f}^! \tilde{f}_!$ induced by base change.
Are these two natural transformations $\tilde{g}_* \to \tilde{g}_* \tilde{f}^! \tilde{f}_!$ necessarily equivalent?

It’s confusing that $f$ appears twice. Do you secretly have in mind the case that $h$ is an isomorphism?

I guess there is no reason why the vertical arrows need to be the same - the question still makes sense in general.  I will edit the question.

What's the map $f_!\tilde g_\ast \to g_\ast \tilde f_!$ ? There is an obvious one if $g$ is proper...

These compositions agree in general, though the proof is reasonably long. The idea is to expand the $*-!$ base change into a factorization, and prove it in the proper/etale cases separately. This is still formal, just using the triangle identities and unravelling base change. I'm writing up a general method for these kinds of problems, should be on arxiv in the new year. Let me know if this proof sketch doesn't suffice.

@DanPetersen The map $f_! \tilde{g}* \to g* \tilde{f}!$ is the one adjoint to $g^* f! \tilde{g}* \xrightarrow{\sim} \tilde{f}! \tilde{g}^* \tilde{g}* \to \tilde{f}!$.

@ChrisH Thanks.  It would be nice to know if there is a proof that only uses Lucas Mann's definition of a six-functor formalism (Definition A.5.7 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2206.02022 or Lecture II of https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/scholze/SixFunctors.pdf), which does not make reference to étale or proper maps.  But in practice, I'm using six-functor formalisms that follow the proper/étale construction strategy, so  I'm okay with reducing to the proper/étale cases if necessary.

Yes, this is the diagram (5HU) of my daily six-functor.
